# How to update multiple rows in mysql using while loop in php

Tags: php, mysqli, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that collect telegram channel username,subscriber count and etc.. 
Now i need to update subscriber count of all telegram channel in my database using telegram api.

see the below code.That only updating first row in database.

```
if($ex[0] == '/upsubs'){
    $upsubs = mysqli_query($db,"SELECt * FROM channel");
    while($up = mysqli_fetch_assoc($upsubs)){
        $ups = $up['c_name'];
        $content1 =file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/bot<API_TOKER>/getChatMembersCount?chat_id=".$ups);
        $obj1 = json_decode($content1, TRUE);
        $subs1 = $obj1['result'];
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE channel SET c_subs = '".$subs1."' WHERE c_name = '".$ups."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging - if you can't trace the code using a debugger, then something like `echo $ups.PHP_EOL;` in the loop to see what values it's using and how many times it goes round the loop.

Comment: What type of bot is that? See: https://www.sitelock.com/blog/2016/05/good-and-bad-internet-bots/

Comment: This is telegram bot